# Create game object from the texture in 2D

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have some texture - a square picture with the painted bricks. And I want to create the element I will use as an obstacles - usual platformer's walls - in my game. So, I can't understand, how can I create this game object? For example, in 3D I can jus to create an object - for example, cube - and drag'n'drop my texture to this object.  But in 2D I can't do the same steps. In 2D, as I understand, I need to create a new game object - sprite - and... what next? Drag'n'drop in this case doesn't work, sprite renderer has some fields I think I need to use - 'Sprite' and 'Matherial", but I can't understand, what exactly I need to do with my texture to have the ability use it here and how exectly I need to use it.

Answer (score 0):

> You mean this?

```
public Texture2D myTexture; // Assuming that it has been linked to a texture imported into your project by drag-n-dropping that texture onto this property using Inspector window

     void Start () 
     {
          gameObject.renderer.material.mainTexture = myTexture;
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

In the image/texture import settings you can choose between many different options, for example: Texture or Sprite.

Sprite takes in sprite image

RawImage takes in pure texture

Image takes in sprite image.

Once you put the image to sprite mode in the import setting, you can then drag the image/sprite to the sprite.